# In PhpMyadmin "collation" suddenly becomes "in use" without touching the database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin, some of the tables that had the collations utff8_general_ci have been changed to "in_use" and their engines have been changed from MyISAM to nothing. The engine type is just left blank in phpmyadmin. This is particularly weird foe me, because I haven't touched the DB at all during the past few days. Can someone help me out for this issue.

Thanks,
Priya

Comment: This really isn't an issue. `in_use` just means something accessed it and the table cache can keep this open for a long time. There is no negative impact from its "in_use" status. I wouldn't worry about this.

Comment: @danblack But, I am not able to open the table. Is there any solution to get access of table?

Comment: show error message and SQL statement.